# How to stop driver from closing in between tests in suites (Appium / Webdriverio)

Tags: typescript, react-native, automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io

I'm trying to test a react native app with the following test suite and cases:

Test case files:

- login.ts
- doActionAfterLogin_A.ts

Test suite:
[login.ts, doActionAfterLogin_A.ts]

**Problem:**
For login.ts I want to set the desired capability appium:noReset = false because I want to test the flow of the fresh install. However, I want to test doActionAfterLogin_A.ts with appium:noReset = true because I don't want to go through the whole fresh installation flow again.

The problem is that in between test cases in the suite, Appium will close the browser/driver and launch again with the same desired capabilities, which in this case appium:noReset will always be false. Is there a way to either:

1. Stop the browser/driver from closing in between test cases
2. Change the desired capabilites in between test cases
3. Is the way I'm structuring my test cases wrong?

Further info: Using Appium, Webdriverio, Mocha, Typescript

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, there is no way to change DesiredCapabilities in between an AppiumDriver session. But in your situation, I think it's best to decouple your Appium setup from your .ts test scripts.

- Create a projectCapabilities.ts to set the AppiumDriver and the Capabilities
- Create a hook where you define your Setup and TearDown
- Create a Mocha Test Suite with a Test Case of each .ts

```
before(setup() {});
it('Test Case Name', testcase1Login(){});
it('Test Case Name', testcase2DoAfterLogin(){});
after(teardown() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the driver capability values via system/env variables. I have a range of default values to fallback on if no system/env variable is found. But if I need to change one of the capabilities for a certain test, I make sure to set the system/env variable first.

Logic for each test would then be:

1. Set system/env variable "noReset" to true or false depending on your test
2. Create instance of driver with capability "noReset" to have value of "noReset" system/env variable
3. Run test logic